C# cannot write to EventLog when Source is defined
I am trying to write to the Windows' EventLog > Windows Logs > Application, I am pretty sure I've created everything that is needed, but when writing to it, it just throws an Unknown error (0xe06d7363) without giving out any information. When checking for the EventSource it does reported that the source exists.
The registry entry that was created, for example:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\MyApp
A ProviderGuid under MyApp
A EventMessageFile under Myapp, that is pointing to %SystemRoot%\System32\mscoree.dll

When attempting to write to the EventLog, the following snippet was used:
if (!SourceExists)
{
    // When debugging, it never went in here because
    // I've already created the source in the registry
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists(Source))
    {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(new EventSourceCreationData("MyApp", "Application"));
        SourceExists = true;
    }
}

using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog())
{
    eventLog.Log = "Application";
    eventLog.Source = "MyApp";
    // the following line will throw Unknown error (0xe06d7363)
    eventLog.WriteEntry("Hello world", EventLogEntryType.Information, 1000);
}

I am using event id 1000 because out of the box, mscoree.dll, has a default format that just lets you dump the string as-is.
What else am I missing?
PS: If I use Application as the Source too, then it would work, but I want to be able to log as MyApp, not Application.

I managed to get it to work, but it turns out I need to introduce 2 more registry entries for it to work. I am unsure if this is something new in Windows 10/11, but I reverse-engineered some of the other Microsoft applications (ex: Microsoft-Windows-RestartManager under EventLog\Application), and that's what they have/did.
You need to add your application's GUID under Publisher. So under EventLog\Application\MyApp, you have ProviderGuid, take that GUID and add a new key under the following location:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers\{your-guid-value-goes-here}
You need to have a (Default) value follow by MessageFileName:

I was using InnoSetup to create my installer and create the necessary Registry entries, here is what I had:
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers\{#MyGuid}"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers\{#MyGuid}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "MessageFileName"; ValueData: "%SystemRoot%\System32\mscoree.dll"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\{#MyAppExeName}"; ValueType: expandsz; ValueName: "ProviderGuid"; ValueData: "{#MyGuid}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\{#MyAppExeName}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "EventMessageFile"; ValueData: "%SystemRoot%\System32\mscoree.dll"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue

Hopefully this would help someone else.
